# How to change the name of an existed app in windows phone store and associate with win store app

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store, windows-phone-store

I've published an app for Windows Phone 8.1 in the store. But I have an app with the same functionality in Windows Store and I've decided to associate them. I've created a new submission (described in MSDN  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/dn642076), but the name field in App Info is disabled. I can't choose the name of my Windows Store app. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: the name you have given for windows phone app will be taken i guess.

Comment: @PrasannaAarthi, I'd like to change the name I've given

Comment: Under the Name in the App Info page of my submission I see the text
"You can reserve another name for this app to use in another language or to change its name. Reserve app name " - do you see something similar? have you tried reserving another name?

Comment: @Jogy, yes, I can reserve another name, but only new name and only as second, not instead of. I can't select name of win store app and associate.

Answer (score 0):

Apps must be published by the same developer account in order to share the same reserved name and app identity.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn646927.aspx